# Finding Pickup Locations (EU, France, UK)

Tags: mail

I will be traveling in France soon.  During this time, I need to pick up some deliveries. Some are with Amazons, and for these, I can easily find pick up locations, but  How would I find pick up locations that support other services at the same time?

I think for US services,  As far as I can remember, I can't choose a pickup location when I order.  Is it some way to know how these companies will behave in a particular country.(I could pick hotel addresses if I know I will be offered different options for delivery.

I don't like to put hotels, but it is OK if I can put a nearby location close to delivery?

Also there pickup locations that can also do parcel forwarding and be used as a regular address?

Comment: In the UK you could ask the sender to use https://inpost.co.uk/ I'm not affiliated with this company

Comment: At least in Paris, pickup locations are fairly common. They are called point de relais. Amazon and most sites offer pickup delivery.

Answer (score 2):

France has a service specifically designed for this sort of thing, called [Poste Restante](https://theworklife.com/experience/poste-restante/). You can send packages to yourself to be collected at a post office. See the link for more details.

> Avec le service Poste restante, vos courriers et colis vous attendent dans le bureau de poste de votre choix : confidentialité assurée et remise en main propre garantie.
>
> With the Poste restante service, your letters and parcels await you in the post office of your choice: confidentiality guaranteed and guaranteed delivery by hand.

Opening times are reasonable business hours:

> French post offices  are generally open 9:00 a.m. to 7:00 p.m. Monday to Friday, and 9:00 a.m. to noon on Saturday. However in smaller towns and villages offices may close earlier and for lunch, while in Paris the main post office is open 24 hours.

Comment: Does Amazon deliver to poste restante?

Comment: I don't know that it doesn't. I don't see why it wouldn't. And OP says he has a solution for Amazon.

Comment: @DJClayworth  European Amazons usually let you pick a pick up location when you order.  The main issue is that I would like everything in one place (Reg. Poste Restante, I doubt it is the same locations, the link says nothing about packages and opening hours are probably limited)

Comment: Edited to explain.

Comment: According to https://www.tourdumonde5continents.com/comment-recevoir-un-colis-ou-un-courrier-nimporte-ou-dans-le-monde-avec-dhl-ou-ups/ it doesn't work with tracking, I think limits delivery services I can use.  Also I will drive in to my destination on a Sunday, so opening hours are important.

Comment: 'Poste restante' addresses usually only work for mail and parcels sent through the 'regular' mail or post service of the relevant country. At least in Europe, many retailers use other competing delivery services (e.g. UPS) and these will probably not deliver to 'poste restante' addresses.

Answer (score 1):

In France there are quite a few networks of delivery locations. Many sites will allow you to pick  a location to deliver to at the time of order (it may in some cases reduce delivery charges).

The issue is that as there are several different networks, it may be difficult to find a single location you can get everything delivered to. A few locations belong to 2 or 3 of the networks, but it's uncommon, as far as I know (though the situation may be different in rural places compared to larger cities).

Note that in many cases, even if you give a regular delivery address, if you are unavailable at delivery time, they will automatically drop it off at the closest delivery point and send you a text message with the details. Some drivers are very prompt to decide you are unavailable :-/

In one of your comments you state you need to pick up on sundays, but THAT is going to be a real challenge.

There are also a few services with automated lockers in some locations (including train stations), but I have never used them so I can’t quite comment.